# Accessing an value in defaultdict and stripping out url portion of it

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a very large defaultdict that has a dict within a dict, the inner dict containing html from an email body. I only want to return an http string from within the inner dict. What's the best way to go about extracting that?

Do I need to convert the dict to another data structure before using regex? Is there a better way? I'm still fairly new to Python and appreciate any pointers.

For example, what I'm working with:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {16: {u'SEQ': 16, u'RFC822': u'Delivered-To: 
somebody@email.com      LOTS MORE HTML until http://the_url_I_want_to_extract.com' }}
```

One thing I've tried is using re.findall on defaultdict which didn't work:

```
confirmation_link = re.findall('Click this link to confirm your registration:<br />"
(.*?)"', body)

for conf in confirmation_link:
    print conf
```

Error:

```
line 177, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What code you have? What problem does it have?

Comment: Tried a few things, such as directly using re, which doesnt work on dicts as far as I can tell. As was as iteritems on body and looking for key.startswith, but just struggling with what direction to go. I'll update the post with some of the stuff I've tried, thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with code that produces and demonstrates a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only only use the regular expression, once you've iterated over your dictionary for the corresponding value:

```
import re

d = defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {16: {u'SEQ': 16, u'RFC822': u'Delivered-To: somebody@email.com      LOTS MORE HTML until http://the_url_I_want_to_extract.com' }}

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    #v is the dictionary that contains your html string:
    str_with_html = v['RFC822']

    #this regular expression starts with matching http, and then 
    #continuing until a white space character is hit.
    match = re.search("http[^\s]+", str_with_html)
    if match:
        print match.group(0)
```

Output:

```
http://the_url_I_want_to_extract.com
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, really appreciate it. That worked and playing with iteritems on the dictionary, I learned something new. :)